# Excel VBA Macro - find text in cell one, replace value in adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel

Working on a vendor's sales document provided by a grocer, which lists the number of units they sold. Issue is that their excel sheet and the way they record sales (which I cannot change) doesn't differentiate between single bars sold and boxes sold - so some rows state "Mint Bar" = 1 sold and some state "Mint Bar Box" = 1 sold. The unit values are the same in the sheet, but the "box" should really = 12 (since a box is 12 units, not just 1).

The second issue is that every time "box" appears that value needs to be n*12 (so 1box*12 = 12 bars).

Thus, I am looking for some code to help me out. I know this is easy in SQL and have less experience running excel macros.

--
Fixed:

Where the Boxes appear in D2, D6, D8, etc:

```
=if(Cell="Box", 12*D2, 12*D6, 12*D8)
```

Drag formula down for all the rows in the sheet.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you have to do this in a macro? I would just add another column that says

`=if(Cell="Mint Bar Box", 12, 1)`

Comment: @Meaghan If needed you can also multiply the number of units sold. If the number of units is in cell B4, use `=if(Cell="Mint Bar Box", 12*B4, B4)`

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj, good call. in fact, based on the title, it seems as if Meaghan already has a quantity column in place, so we would not even need to add another column

Comment: Or even make it generic by using `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" BOX",UPPER(desc_cell)),12,1)*qty_cell` or (if "Box" is always the last bit) `=IF(RIGHT(desc_cell,4)=" Box",12,1)*qty_cell`

Comment: thanks everyone! I was making it too complicated.